# Specify Double-Click event for a Control in Visual Studio Designer

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, silverlight, xaml

When you Double-Click on a `Control` in the Visual Studio Designer, you automatically subscribe to some `event` and an Event Handler is generated in the code behind file.

Double-Clicking on the following Controls subscribes to the corresponding event

- `UserControl` - *Loaded*
- `Button` - *Click*
- `TextBox` - *TextChanged*
- `Grid` - *No event*
  etc.

How is this specified, is it a Visual Studio setting? Can this be overrideen and how can you specify which event you want to link to Double-Click for e.g. a Custom Control?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a [DefaultEventAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaulteventattribute.aspx) that controls can specify. The designer knows to read this attribute and uses it to determine which event to use as the default.

```
[DefaultEvent("DoubleClick")]
public class MyClass {

    public event EventHandler DoubleClick;

}
```

There is also a DefaultPropertyAttribute which is significantly less useful. It just determines the default property name to select in the property grid when the control is selected in the designer.

Comment: And if you want the final user to DoubleClick on your control to access the function, use "DoubleClick" instead of "Click"

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see this when looking in `TextBox` with Reflector, I only saw `ContentProperty("Text")` etc. Anyway, extra + for the DefaultPropertyAttribute, two in one :)

Answer (score 0):

*If wanting to do this in the editor.*
For VS2017 (and beyond I suspect).  In Designer:

- Select the control on the form
- In the Properties Window, select the Events icon
- The list of available events for that control will be shown
- Double-click the name of the desired event.

This also works for deleting the auto-generated code.  Remove the name of the event handler for that event.  It will get removed from the *.designer.cs file.  Note that you still need to remove the handler code in the form source.