# Visual Studio: replace default doubleclick-event

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, events, attributes

I am aware of [DefaultEventAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaulteventattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but I am still a bit clueless of how to implement it correctly.

I have made a simple control class that inherits from NumericUpDown:

```
public class NumericControl : System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown
```

I want to use it in my project instead of a default NumericUpDown control, and I want to replace a default doubleclick-generated event in visual studio. By default it's:

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

And I want it to be

```
private void numericUpDown1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
```

Thanks in advance.

*Edit:*
No, no, I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653049/specify-double-click-event-for-a-control-in-visual-studio-designer) already. But I just want to simply replace one event by another (and both of them are already built-in in the control). I don't want to assign it to some custom event. My issue is much simpler but I still struggled with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specify Double-Click event for a Control in Visual Studio Designer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653049/specify-double-click-event-for-a-control-in-visual-studio-designer)

Comment: You can create own delegate for event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just add `DefaultEvent` attribute to your control class with another event name, it should work fine
(rebuild projects before check after adding attribute)

```
[DefaultEvent("KeyPress")]
public class NumericControl : System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown
```

Comment: Yes, yes and yes!
For some stupid reason I typed [DefaultEvent("OnKeyPress")], instead of a simply KeyPress. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Gattuso, oh, i see. but you are fine now ;)