# IDE control double click behaviour

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ide

In VB6, a double click on a control on a form jumped to its default sub, for example MyControl_Click.

When the Click event for this control doesn't exist yet in VS2017 for this control, VS2017 creates this event for me when I double click the control.

I would rather like VS2017 to jump to the first defined event (if one exists).

Is there a setting in VS2017 to change the behaviour of the IDE?

Comment: I'm almost certain that there isn't.

Comment: I'm not aware of an option to change this in Visual Studio. You could try searching [the Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/) for and extension that provides the behaviour you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify Double-Click event for a Control in Visual Studio Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653049/specify-double-click-event-for-a-control-in-visual-studio-designer)

Answer (score 0):

There is not such option in any Visual Studio. I also don't see any advantages of navigating to first defined event on double click, there are lot of ways to go to event handler of control.